# How can I regain my Instagram account after the phone number got invalid?

Tags: instagram, account-recovery, instagram-account

My Instagram account has been suspended by the Instagram team, possibly because I had not used it for a while, and I tried to log in from within a different region from where I used to do.

When I typed in the username and password, the pop-up menu shows up to let me type in the verification number. There are two verification options - phone number and email - but I no longer retain the phone number (I unsubscribed the service) and I don't know which email address it is (and maybe I no longer retain the email as well...).

In this case, can I regain my Instagram account? Again, I have the correct username and password.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, request it from within an app, not from web.**

The Instagram doesn't have an user-friendly support page on the web, but they have on mobile the app (in my case it is iOS). Send a request by the following steps:

1. Open the Instagram app and go to the log-in page
2. Tap *Get help signing in.*.
3. The page goes to the verification page. At this stage, first fill in your username and tap *Send Login Link*, even though your email is invalid. They show your email with a slight hint (e.g. `my******g***2*@g****.com`).
4. Tap *Need more help?* on the same page. **Even though you know your email is invalid, you must first send a link at the process *3***; otherwise the tapped link goes to the generic support page.
5. If you tap *Need more help?* **after** you finish *Send Login Link*, the special support page shows up, letting you contacting the support team. Fill in the followings:

   - The email you used to register the account (even though it is invalid now)
   - The email you want them to get in contact
   - Some questions (if it is a company account, if the photo is yours, etc...)
   - And additional details

Then wait for them to get in contact with you!

Comment: @pnuts They sent back an email quickly, likely within 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access of associated email or your account is not linked with Facebook. You can not recover your account. See [Instagram help](https://help.instagram.com/409847499070242):

> If you can't access the email you registered with and you didn't link your Instagram account to Facebook, we're not able to give you access to this account.