# Instagram confirmed account but can't get the security code

Tags: instagram, account-recovery, instagram-account

What do I do? I don't have access to the number it's sending the security code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two more method to reset password other than phone number:

- Using email address
- Using Facebook account

If you don't have access of these above two also then don't try from web. Use Instagram app and get help. From [Instagram Help Centre](https://help.instagram.com/409847499070242):

> If you can't remember your password, you can reset it using your email address, phone number or Facebook account. **If you're not able to reset your password this way, open the Instagram app for additional help.**

This [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/111493/87130) explains how to reset password from Instagram app.